# Map if-function on a list

Tags: functions, map, excel

I need to convert a battery charging mechanism from Excel into Mathematica.
This Excel function is about deciding if the charge/decharge rate is positive, then multiply with efficiency factor, otherwise stay 0:

> =If(Charging/Decharging rate>0 ; (Charging/Decharging rate*efficiency); 0)

The problem is i'm new to mathematica and i can't get this function to work with setting this up like this (after defining the charge/decharge rate imported from a spreadsheet as **test** and **n** as efficiency as list):

```
f[x_] := (If[x > 0, x*n1, 0])
charge = (f /@ test)
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: Can you give a (small) sample value for the `test` variable?  The code you posted looks fine to me, assuming that `test` is a list of numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @Szabolcs found a solution, i only had to flatten the imported list :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `test` is a list of numbers, your code works fine:

```
f[x_] := (If[x > 0, x*n1, 0])

test = {1, 2, 3, -1};

f /@ test
(* {n1, 2 n1, 3 n1, 0} *)
```

If you import `test` from an Excel file, Mathematica might give you a 2D array (Excel sheets are like matrices).  You can use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to convert it to a flat list, or alternatively use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) with [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All.html) (please check the documentation).

If `test` is a list of numbers, a more efficient way may be

```
charge = n1*Clip[test, {0, Infinity}]
```

To give a more specific answer, we need to know the structure of the `test` variable that you have.

Comment: Just saw your comment up there, i only had to flatten the imported list and the output now is just how i wanted it to be (and gives the same output as excel). The list itself was only 1 column filled with numbers in the range from -1 to 1 (roughly) and about 35000 rows long. It was imported as an .xls. Thanks for your solution, you helped me very much!

Comment: Additionally, your more efficient way works like a charm!